# How to send an email using php

Tags: php, phpmailer

When I execute this code, a new tab is opened. It displays my code. How do I fix this?

```
<?php

$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Send mail using gmail
if($send_using_gmail){
   $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
   $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
   $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
   $mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
   $mail->Username = "myemailid@gmail.com"; // GMAIL username
   $mail->Password = "mypassword"; // GMAIL password
}

//Typical mail data
$mail->AddAddress('myemailid@gmail.com', 'Name');
$mail->SetFrom('myemailid@gmail.com', 'Name');
$mail->Subject = "My Subject";
$mail->Body = "Mail contents";

try{
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Success!";
} catch(Exception $e){
  //Something went bad
  echo "Fail :(";
}

?>
```

I am trying to send an email using PHP here.

Comment: @karan That question doesn't show how to use `PHPMailer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

try this one it worked for me. If didnt work let me know

Comment: Thank you...It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will not answer OP's question but i want to make this in people's attention, Please excuse me...

Source :- https://sendgrid.com/blog/gmail-dmarc-update-2016/

> What is Gmail changing?

June of 2016 Gmail will change its DMARC policy from p=”none” to p=”reject.” This means any message sent using gmail.com in the from address, will have to originate from Gmail’s infrastructure.

> What does this mean for me?

It depends. If you have any mail streams that send messages using gmail.com in the from address, you will have to make changes before June, or risk having those messages filtered or blocked outright.

If you only send email using your own domain or another domain that you control, you have nothing to worry about. However, it’s not uncommon for some applications or websites to send messages using their users’ email addresses. For example, if a user wants to send a message to their friend using your platform, it could make sense to send the message using their personal email address. If their email address happens to be a gmail.com address, this message will no longer deliver once these changes take place. A good alternative to sending mail from your user’s email address is to use their name in the friendly from. A “friendly from” is when you use a name to appear as the from address, instead of the email address itself:

exampleuser@yahoo.com can be sent as “Example User”

This way your recipients still recognize the individual that sent the message, and you’re no longer at risk of violating Gmail’s DMARC policy.